# Syntax Type Name(Type) in function

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I found in sample code strange syntax. I have no idea what this code does, but looks nothing.
What does syntax `type Name(Type)` in function means?

```
void doJob()
{
...
bool SetForward(bool); //strange line
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a function declaration.

They don't have to be at file scope, but it's fairly rare to see them inside functions if you're not reading relatively ancient C code.

Comment: To expand on the answer, functions declarations are also known as function prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

Function Declarations are usually done at the top of your program so that the main can access all of them !! However , what if you want your main not able to access that function ? You simply declare its prototype in the function which is going to use it !! Another Example can be seen a private function in a class which can only be accessed by class methods & not by the main program !!